# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http.WebHost, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In Visual Studio 2012 I created an ASP.NET MVC 4 project where the target framework is the .NET Framework 4.5. When I deployed my project to a web server it gave the following error:

```
    Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http.WebHost, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file 
specified.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
 Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where
it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or 
assembly 'System.Web.Http.WebHost, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
 PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.
 The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error: 


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34237
```

Comment: Did you use web deploy or how did you deploy it?

Comment: @John i published and then copy that files to host

Comment: Are you able to directly publish to the server? Or use the web deploy zip or something? That will make sure all the files are included. Also make sure that MVC has been installed on the server.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Check the bin folder of your deployed project. It should contain System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll.
If this dll is in this folder, check it version. If it isn't 4.0.0.0, then you should deploy version 4.0.0.0 or change your web config to use other version (not really good idea because of dependencies)

Comment: I told you several option to try. Which one did you try?

Comment: @IAfanasov I have the same issue and I confirmed that I have the System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll file in my bin folder of the deployed project but still I got the same error. What's your thought about it?Do I still miss on something?Thanks

Comment: Have you checked version of dll and version of project reference?

Comment: where can I find System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll?

Comment: I don't have this file System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll how can I have this?

Answer (score 31):

I had the same issue today during deployment. I was able to fix it by marking the assembly to be copied to the deployment file.

In order to do this, in my Visual Studio project, select the `System.Web.Http.Webhost` assembly in your references and alter the 'Copy Local' property to True. I had to repeat this for a few other assemblies that were missing.

Thanks to this website for the tips - http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx/

Comment: @Sthan   this one helped me.

Answer (score 12):

Try to reinstall Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi package. Open Package Manager Console and type:

```
Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi -reinstall
```

Be careful, this command will **remove all dependencies** and you will have to install them manually.

Comment: Edit packages.config and comment out all the webapi references, then you can run install without first doing uninstall.

Answer (score 4):

I had this error with an old project that I was going back to do a bit of work on.  It turns out the project wasn't actually using WebApi so I uninstalled Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi using NuGet.  That solved the problem for me.

If I'd actually have needed WebApi I'm sure installing it again would have fixed the error too.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this today after setting up a new Team City Build Agent.  The new agent didn't have MVC 4 installed, perhaps part of the problem.  Fortunately, I found [this article](http://www.jeffwids.com/post/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-systemwebhttpwebhost) which lead me to the solution.  In Team City, I just updated the Build Step for the Nuget Restore so that it doesn't use the local cache.

[image]

This works because the cache may have been established by build runners with different (MVC) frameworks installed already.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is answered but I thought I'd add something.

Every time I set "copy local" to true on a file causing the error I'd publish it and just get another one. So I just selected all of the files under references and set them all to true. This fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Important: This error message can be caused because you are deploying a 4.5 project to a server that doesn't have 4.0 installed. Make sure you have the .NET Framework version installed in IIS for the project you need. Some of these DLLs by default won't copy up, because it uses the core project DLL normally. Check to make sure your production server has the .NET version you're going with. I experienced this myself with a 4.5 project on a 4.0 server.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure ASP.NET MVC 4 is installed on your server. Check it in the following location -

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4