# How to fix a runtime error on web deployment?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, deployment, web-deployment

This is my first time to deploy an asp.net mvc4 website. I'm not using an IIS Manager to deploy my website but instead I just manually uploaded all the project files from the web host server. After I deployed all the files to the web host server I tested it and I've got a runtime error. This error captures me but I don't know how to fix them.

**Stack Trace:**

> [FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http.WebHost, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
>      MyFirstMVCApp.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in c:\Users\MarkTim\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MyFirstMVCApp\MyFirstMVCApp\Global.asax.cs:26

To help you figure out more about the runtime error on my web deployment. Please visit this link below and correct me of what I've been missing and did something incorrectly. Thank you. Here's the link:

http://mitkram84-001-site1.smarterasp.net/

Comment: are you resolved this dependency on your project ?

Comment: It's running perfectly on my local machine. I'm not sure what settings do I need to take in order to fix this runtime error.

Comment: did you check both web.config files on local server and your web host server ?

Comment: I have no idea how to resolve this dependency on my project.

Comment: Yes I checked them and they are both in same configuration

Comment: check your bin folder contains the same dll with version 4.0.0.0

Comment: I double checked again my bin folder on my root server has same all files copied from the references in my project solution. I'm not sure if they are in version 4.0.0.0.

Comment: Run your project in release mode. then publish the code and deploy it.

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2012 ultimate and if I publish my project it would give you the option to publish to Windows Azure, that's why I can't do by Publish. I just wander why I won't load the assembly file and it associated with Global.asax file where I set the startup view.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533868/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-web-http-webhost-version-4-0-0-0-cultu