# getting "Could not load file or assembly" when adding reference of a downloaded source project to another project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have downloaded a source code from github , and added the downloaded project references to another project which i created seperately now when I am running the  project which i have created ,  i am getting the following error message:

Server Error in '/' Application.

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http.WebHost, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: Add reference to System.Web.Http.WebHost in your project.

Comment: Can u check the version of your dll which you added ?

Comment: What is version of your dot net framework ?

Comment: ###See also
[Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http.WebHost, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533868/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-web-http-webhost-version-4-0-0-0-cultu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue can be solved by [Reinstalling the NuGet package](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/reinstalling-packages), which fixes broken dependencies.

> In package manager, run `Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi -reinstall`.

Comment: I even tried this but still it is not working. iam getting the same error

Comment: i reinstalled package  for rwice , now it is not displaying any error. it is working fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below lines in web config Configuration Section.  right click on the dll and find the version and then change the old version and new version values in the below code in web config.

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
          <assemblyBinding>
        <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http.WebHost" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          </assemblyBinding>
       </runtime>
</configuration>
```